# Is there a way to split a string containing two paths to a list\tuple containing the paths?

Tags: python, string

For example:

```
str= "C:\f.txt C:\f 1.txt"
```

How do I split it to:

```
C:\f.txt and C:\f 1.txt
```

I can't use split(" ") because the file name or the directory can contain a space.

Comment: Then what do you want to decide what is the split point? What if you had a single file called "C:\f.txt C:\f 1.txt"? You'll probably need to introduce a delimiter into the string that you can split on.

Comment: `re.findall(r'([A-Z]:.*?(?=\s*[A-Z]:|$))', ...)`? - search on drive letter.

Comment: Yeah, drive letter is the key here.

Comment: how was the original string created? Some bad practices were used there that will complicate your code further on. I would suggest going back a step.

Comment: You can even use `split` and then loop over the generated list, and `join` where the case

Comment: `list_of_paths = ['C:\\{}'.format(a) for a in str.split('C:\\') if a != '']` but you shouldn't use `str` as variable name, use something else.

Comment: `re.split(r'\s(?![^C])', s)` as well

Answer (score 0):

There are some good `regex` solutions in the comments, but one that just uses pure Python could be:

```
s = "C:\f.txt C:\f 1.txt"
i = [i for i,c in enumerate(s) if c == ":"][1]
p = (s[:i-2], s[i-1:])
```

which gives `p` (the parts) as:

```
('C:\x0c.txt', 'C:\x0c 1.txt')
```